# Problem About Equality: Is 2=1?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

As we know that
$$\frac{1}{0} = ∞ \implies \frac{1}{∞} = 0 \implies 1 = 0.∞$$
Now let $x=0$ and $y=0$ then
$$x+y=0 \implies \frac{x+y}{1}=0 \implies \frac{x+y}{0}=1$$
and $x+y=0$ so
$$\frac{0}{0}=1$$
Similarly, as $\frac{2}{2}=1$ and $\frac{5}{5}=1$

Now we know that any number multiply by zero is equal to zero so
$$ (2)0 = 0 \rightarrow(1)$$
And
$$\frac{0}{0} = \frac{0}{0}$$
By eq(1)
$$\frac{(2)0}{0} = \frac{(1)0}{0}$$
$$2\frac{0}{0} = 1\frac{0}{0}$$
as $\frac{0}{0} = 1$ then
$$2(1) = 1(1)$$
$$2 = 1$$

Comment: Division by zero is not defined. It could be anything from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ as well as any complex number.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/417280/continued-fraction-fallacy-1-2/

Comment: I suggest that this question be placed under the "recreational mathematics" category.

Comment: Useful to read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_by_zero

Comment: Now there is another problem if x=y ⇒ x+x-x = y+y-y ⇒ 2x-x=2y-y ⇒ 2x-2y=x-y ⇒ 2(x-y)=(x-y) and by cancellation law ⇒ 2=1

Comment: This is why analysis exists.

Comment: This question did not deserve all those downvotes. Its only flaw is that it doesn't 100% clearly state the question (where is my mistake?).

Answer (score 4):

$\infty$ is not a number and $\frac{0}{0}$ is not determined.

Comment: I would add "real" in front of number.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simpler version of your argument:

$$2 = 2 \cdot 1 = 2 \cdot \frac{0}{0} \overset{*}{=} \frac{2 \cdot 0}{0} = \frac{0}{0} = 1$$

The problematic step is highlighted with an asterisk. Every *other* step is okay, provided that we *define* $0/0$ to equal $1$. What this teaches us is that we cannot both have our cake, and eat it too; if we define $0/0$ to equal $1$, then the familiar law:

$$a \cdot \frac{b}{c} = \frac{a \cdot b}{c}$$

no longer holds.

Answer (score 2):

Your starting point is not at all an identity between numbers, but only a mnemonic trick for the statement:

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)}=0 \Rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow a}{\dfrac{1}{f(x)}}=\infty
$$
Properly using the definition of limit you can show that:
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)}=\infty \Rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow a}{\dfrac{1}{f(x)}}=0
$$
That we can ''remember'' quikly as 
$$
\dfrac{1}{\infty}=0
$$
But we cannot proof that
$$
\left(\lim_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)}=0 \quad  \land \quad \lim_{x\rightarrow a}{g(x)}=\infty \right)\Rightarrow \lim_{x\rightarrow a}{f(x)g(x)}=1
$$
 as in your $ 1=0\cdot \infty$.
 So all your deduction is based on the wrong idea that $ \infty$ can be treated as a number ,but it is only a symbol used to represent a particular limit.